# Using Numpy to find a value and update

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list and I wish to find a value using numpy and update its neighbor value in a 2D array

```
myList = np.array([['kim' '0'],
    ['jong' '0'],
    ['un' '0'],
    ['is' '0'],
    ['here' '1']])

np.where(myList == 'is')// some operation to update from '0' to '1'. Please help
```

Result

```
['kim' '0'],
['jong' '0'],
['un' '0'],
['is' '1'],
['here' '1']
```

Comment: It seems that you've forgotten the commas between your items. Please reformat your data or make it clear what's the real format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way, you have defined your array is totally wrong. I guess you wanted a list of lists. But `['kim' '0']` is not a valid list, due to missing comma between elements. ON fixing that, it would be easy to do whatever you want

That being said, if your list is always going to contain only 2 elements, consider using dict

```
>>> myList = np.array([['kim', '0'],
...     ['jong', '0'],
...     ['un', '0'],
...     ['is', '0'],
...     ['here', '1']])
>>> row = np.where(myList[:,0] == 'is')
>>> myList[row, 1] = 1
>>> myList
array([['kim', '0'],
       ['jong', '0'],
       ['un', '0'],
       ['is', '1'],
       ['here', '1']], dtype='<U4')
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is currently "not really 2D", in that `['kim' '0']` will be evaluated to `['kim0']` (to check this, access `myList[0]`). Also, you initialize your numbers as strings (`'0'` instead of simply `0`).

If you do the initialization correctly, you'd get something like this:

```
myList = np.array([['kim', 0],
    ['jong', 0],
    ['un', 0],
    ['is', 0],
    ['here', 1]])
```

Then your operation is already (almost correct). Now simply look at the column that contains the words for your `where` condition:

```
selector = np.where(myList[:,0] == "is") # look for the word only in the first column
```

And then finally change the value:

```
myList[selector, 1] = 1 # access the "value column"
```

Should you want to increase the value, simply do `+=1 instead of = 1`, or you could even stick to your string-formatted values (care with the initialization, though; you still need the commas), and then assign `'1'` instead.